# Avoid Racing Condition between resources in a Terraform Module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have these two resource definitions in a terraform module:

```
resource "null_resource" "install_dependencies" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "pip install -r requirements.txt -t . ; exit"
  }



  triggers = {
    dependencies_versions = filemd5(".${var.package_requirements_path}")
  }
}


data "archive_file" "lambda_source_package" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = ".${var.source_directory}"
  output_path = var.zipped_lambda

}
```

The null resource installs a host of dependencies. These resources are then archived by the `lambda_source_package`. However, I find that, `data "archive_file" "lambda_source_package"` executes before all the pip packages are installed.

To solve this, I used the `depends_on` meta-argument for this. I realized this also doesn't solve the issue since terraform isn't able to find the zip file generated by `data "archive_file" "lambda_source_package"` before it completes execution. The output error message is `│ Error: unable to load "../outputs/xx.zip": open ../outputs/xx.zip: no such file or directory`

[The documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) says that, the `depends_on` argument "create more conservative plans that replace more resources than necessary" and hence it is not advisable to use it especially when creating a module(which is my use case).

The documentation also suggests that "Instead of depends_on, we recommend using expression references to imply dependencies when possible.". What does this mean? How can I apply it to my use-case?

Comment: Usually an implicit dependency is created when arguments/attributes from one resource are referenced in the second resource. In your case, that would mean to create an implicit dependency between the `null_resource` and the data source. However, I don't think this can be done when the `null_resource` is used.

Comment: ok..is there any resource I can I use to archive the same effect as a `null_resource`?

Comment: Not sure, maybe the external data source could be of use: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source.

Comment: @MarkoE, external data sources need to be used to fetch something which isn't possible with existing data providers. To create something, you have to use `resource` providers. 
Although you can install something with external data sources but it goes against the very own definition of it.

Comment: @theSekyi, It's not a good practice to install something as part of deployment pipelines. If you are using a docker/VM why don't you install `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .` during the build time. 
As far as terraform is concerned installations should happen on target infrastructure not on the host executing it.

Comment: The infrastructure provisioner should ideally not be packaging your lambda. The build and packaging for it would be part of that application's workflow and pipeline.

Comment: If you still intend to install packages on the host executing terraform, you could refer similar discussion [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11806). Lot of options proposed.

Comment: I do agree with the other commenters above that this seems like a use-case that isn't really suited to Terraform -- this is something better orchestrated by a traditional build workflow tool like GNU Make, or whatever is idiomatic to use to build packages in Python. However, FWIW the statement in the docs "This is especially likely when you use `depends_on` for modules" is intended to mean using `depends_on` _inside a `module` block_, not with the `resource` blocks declared inside a module.

Comment: I will move the pip installations into a script.